# Reg. Linking External Library to Project using CMake

Tags: cmake, hdf5, ros, catkin

I am trying to build a project using an external library, but the system keeps thinking it needs to use the library inside usr/lib which is broken. I wish to instead use the library that is built within the address: /home/CMake-hdf5-1.8.18/build/HDF5-1.8.18-Linux/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.18/include. This is the CMakeLists.txt. My intended solution are the two lines under #Add hdf5 library.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(scan_to_cloud_converter)

# List C++ dependencies on ros packages
set( ROS_CXX_DEPENDENCIES
  roscpp
  pcl_ros
  pcl_conversions)

# Find catkin and all required ROS components
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${ROS_CXX_DEPENDENCIES})
find_package(PCL REQUIRED QUIET)

# Set include directories
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Declare info that other packages need to import library generated here
catkin_package( )

#Create node
add_executable( scan_to_cloud_converter_node
src/scan_to_cloud_converter_node.cpp
src/scan_to_cloud_converter.cpp )

#Add hdf5 library
link_directories(/home/CMake-hdf5-1.8.18/build/HDF5-1.8.18-Linux/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.18/include)
target_link_libraries(scan_to_cloud_converter_node libhdf5)

# No need to link against pcl (using header only libraries)
target_link_libraries( scan_to_cloud_converter_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(scan_to_cloud_converter_node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

#Install node
install(TARGETS scan_to_cloud_converter_node
RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION} )
```

This is the error message I am still getting however:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so', needed by '/home/catkin_ws/devel/lib/scan_to_cloud_converter/scan_to_cloud_converter_node'.  Stop.
```

I've done research on this error and it is because it is still looking into /usr/lib, and there is no library libhdf5.so there as the symlink is broken. So how do I get it to instead look at the other address for that library?

Comment: strange that your library is in `.../include` rather than `.../lib`. Anyway, should you not write `target_link_libraries(scan_to_cloud_converter_node hdf5)` ?

Comment: Hmm, there actually is a /lib folder with libhdf5.a, should I redirect the link to this? And should I have that target_link_libraries line or not?

Comment: So I tried with /lib folder as well but getting the same error. My hunch is that it is still looking in /usr/lib without being redirected to this new address, so not sure how to change that.

Comment: Could you try `target_link_libraries(scan_to_cloud_converter_node /home/CMake-hdf5-1.8.18/build/HDF5-1.8.18-Linux/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.18/lib/libhdf5.a)`. Do you have a `libhdf5.so` somewhere ?

Comment: make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home//CMake-hdf5-1.8.18/build/HDF5-1.8.18-Linux/HDF_Group/HD‌​F5/1.8.18/lib/libhdf‌​5.a', needed by '/home/cakin_ws/devel/lib/scan_to_cloud_converter/scan_to_cloud_converter_node'.  Stop. is the error i get when I try above ^

Comment: Yes, I have it in usr/lib/x86.../ but the symlink is broken for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linking a cmake project with hdf5, I suggest to use the `find_package` feature of cmake.

Include the line

```
find_package(HDF5)
```

in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Then, you can use `target_link_libraries(your_lib ${HDF5_C_LIBRARIES})` to link appropriately. The include directories are stored in `${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS}`.

Now, to the point of your question that is to select a specific HDF5 location, issue the command

```
export HDF5_ROOT=/home/CMake-hdf5-1.8.18/build/HDF5-1.8.18-Linux/HDF_Group/HD‌​F5/1.8.18
```

before issuing cmake. You need to have a clear cache for this to work:

```
rm -r CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles
```